# jQuery Mobile 1.3 listview autocomplete disable autocorrect

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, autocorrect

Is there a way to disable autocorrect in the jQuery Mobile 1.3 listview when it is being used for autocomplete?

```
<label for="searchCity">Enter a city name</label>
    <ul id="searchCity" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="e.g. New York City"></ul>
```

Since this is a UL tag the typical `autocorrect="off"` is not working.

Comment: If you mean the autocorrect in the searchfield, you can disable it using `autocorrect="off"`

Comment: That does not work as this sources from a UL based tag which is why I created this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the below line to activate `autocorrect=off`.

```
$('input[data-type=search]').attr('autocorrect', 'off');
```

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/F3r37/3/)**

Comment: Fantastic.  Works perfectly.